# Do we need to reboot RHEL Servers, after making changes for control-alt-delete override?

Tags: redhat, virtual-machines, kernel, rhel6, patch-management

We are planning on disabling the RHEL Server reboot triggered by control-alt-delete.

for which we are going to follow the Steps mentioned [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/disabling-rebooting-using-ctrl-alt-del).
However, that link does not say whether we need to reboot the server after making that change for it to take effect.

So can someone help me here and let us know if we need a reboot or does it take effect without a reboot? Also, share any links that have a better solution or implementation steps.

I've just mentioned rhel as the OS version as we have few servers on rhel 4 few of them on rhel 5 ... so on

thanks in advance and sorry for the bad language.

Comment: no need to reboot the servers after making changes.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del works perfectly for testing this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that support for the `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.override` file mentioned in product documentation only works for RHEL 6 servers using upstart version upstart-0.6.5-12.el6  and higher. Modifications are applied immediately and do not require a restart/reload.

System that haven't been patched and which are still running older versions (i.e. RHEL <= 6.2) of upstart still need to modify the master configuration file `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf` AFAIK changing this file is also effective immediately.

RHEL 4 & 5 require modifications of `/etc/inittab` followed by a reload of init with [`telinit -q`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/telinit).

For distributions using systemd such as RHEL 7 use:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
```

Comment: possible typo: that would be `telinit q` (without the minus)

Comment: That could well be the case. `q` or `Q` is indeed the correct  *”command”* and there is no *option* `-q` (I will probably retire before understanding Linux completely)